# jcarousel not working on block?

Tags: 7, blocks, javascript

1) Place this module directory in your modules folder (this will usually be
   "sites/all/modules/").

2) Enable the module within your Drupal site at Administer -> Site Building ->
   Modules (admin/build/modules).

I have installed jcarousel module as shown in the above steps.
After that I have create a new views (block) and then added format jcarousel
On the settings I have added auto scroll after 2 seconds
But it does not scroll at all
Also previous and next button when clicked does work

What am I missing?

Comment: Works by me but only with jQuery version 1.8 and lower.

Answer (score 0):

**Works by me but only with jQuery version 1.8 and lower.**

The above comment worked like charm!!!
I had jquery 1.10 so i downgraded it to jquery 1.8